# how to convert BufferedImage to Printable so I can use printJob

Tags: java, printing

I have already written code that will let me print my frame, but now I want to use printJob since it gives user more print option(such as selecting which printer to use). Is there a quick way to covert BufferedImage to Printable so i can use printjob in my code? thx

```
if(command.equals("Print")){
         //saves image as temp and then prints it 

    File out = new File("temp.jpg");
    BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage((int) frame.getWidth(), 
                        (int) frame.getHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );

    frame.paintAll(myImage.createGraphics());
    try{
        ImageIO.write(myImage, "jpg", out);
        PrintImage.printImage("temp.jpg");
    }catch (IOException exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [getGraphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics%28%29) to get the frame's underlying Graphics object, then pass that to the [print](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html#print%28java.awt.Graphics,%20java.awt.print.PageFormat,%20int%29) method of a [PrinterJob](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html).